# Internet explorer problem

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am creating an aspx page which appears fine in mozilla firefox but does not look so great in Internet explorer. In Mozilla its appearing something of this format:

```
<form>
some stuff
<div class="left">
<div class="right">
</form>
```

but looking at the source code of the page loaded in IE 8, it looks sometbhing like this:

```
<form>
some stuff
</form>
<div class="left">
<div class="right">
```

What approach should I take to start fixing it? So far I've tried playing around with the css and fixing paddings and margins but nothing works :/

Thanks so much
C

Comment: I guess your html is not well formed so that your dom gets a little bit messed up. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Could you post the original code you wrote, rather than the source as viewed from Firefox/IE?

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP's code is just pseudocode to illustrate his point. If the left and right divs are floated, you might need to add a clearing element after them, to make the form expand around it.

```
<form>    
  <div class="left">Stuff</div>
  <div class="right">Stuff</div>
  <br style="clear: both;" />
</form>
```

There are better methods than `<br style="clear:both; />`, but you can try it to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Yes, correct it is just pseudocode. I will try the clearing element. thanks

Comment: @C. - I've deleted my answer since I'd basically told you to fix your HTML, which is a redundant point if it is pseudocode. Would have helped if you'd made it a bit clearer that's what it was.